# scan computer for a file and output folder location

Tags: vbscript, server, system-administration

I need to take a list of computers (IP or PC name) that are all on the same domain in CSV format. Scan each computer for a specific folder name. The folder will be arcXXXof. The x's are a hash and change for each PC. If the folder is found it needs to output the folder path to a CSV and append with each computer scanned. My programming is limited and I only really know Java. Since this will be run from a server it will need local administrative privileges to run on the local machines. My manager suggested I use VBS, but I have never written in that before.

My current snag is getting an error "expected then" Here's my loop.

Sub Recurse(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFolder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath) 'reads Folders pulled from recursion

```
Dim objSubFolder

dim folderStart 'grabs the first 2 characters of the file name. Should match 'of' if correct folder
Dim folderEnd 'grabs the last 6 (test) characters of the folder name, should match arc.txt if correct

Global checkEnd
set checkEnd = "arc" 'checks for "arc" at ending

Global checkStart
set checkStart = "of" 'used to check if folder name is correct path



For Each objSubFolder in objFolder  'for every Folder scanned
'Scans the name of the Folder, objSubFolder, for an ending of “arc", and beginning of “of” (testing)
set folderName = objSubFolder.name
Set folderEnd = right(folderName, 3) 
set folderStart = left(folderName, 2)
dim folderName

    if folderName = testFolderName
    then WScript.Echo objSubFolder
    'If folderEnd = checkEnd and
    'If folderStart = checkStart

    'Add Folder location to array, set array to next object
    'Then fLocations(i) = object.GetAbsolutePathName(objSubFolder) and i = i+1 
else
    End If
Next
'recursive for searching new folder
For Each objSubFolder in objFolder.Subfolders
    Call Recurse(objSubFolder.Path)
Next
```

Comment: I apologize for not explaining well. The script needs to search for the file and output it's folder path, not the file itself.

Comment: Might be better to put the power of each PC to work for you and deploy a login script that searches the user's PC when they login and then writes to a shared network text file. How many PCs need to be searched?

Comment: This could be handy! However, I still do not know how to do this :) About 120 computers need to be searched.

Comment: Your question may be considered too broad for SO. You may want to update your question with the specific VBScript issue you're struggling with. Are you getting an error? Are you having trouble with recursion? Reading computer names from a text file? Etc. Posting the whole script and asking for the blanks to be filled may earn you  downvotes or close votes. Focus on a specific problem you're having and we'll do our best to help.

Comment: Thanks I adjusted my post to reference a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks! That's really good. I used a test variable that just contains a string for now to see if everything else works to find a specific folder I created on my PC. I am getting an error "Expected Then" when it gets to my loop. Adjusted my code.

Comment: `Then` is always on the same line as `If`. See the `If...Then` construct in my answer for an example.

Comment: Also there is no `Global` keyword. Anything not in a subroutine is essentially global. Just use `Dim`. Finally, you only use `Set` for objects, not for intrinsic types (strings, numbers, bools, etc). So, `checkEnd = "arc"`.

Comment: Finally it runs! or at least echo's Probably more bugs to iron out, but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. If you run into any more issues that can't be solved by searching Google/SO, feel free to submit a new question.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped, please upvote and/or accept it as an answer.

Comment: I did upvote, however I am to new for it to be shown as public. Accepted as answer :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you could use a regex to match the name. Define it up front, in your global scope:

```
Dim re
Set re = New RegExp
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Pattern = "^arc\w{3}of$"
```

I'm using `\w`, which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. You can change this if you're expecting only digits (`\d`) or something else for these three chars.

Then, in your `Recurse` function, test the folder name against it:

```
For Each objSubFolder in objFolder.SubFolders

    ' See if this folder name matches our regex...
    If re.Test(objSubFolder.Name) Then

        ' Match. Just display for now...
        WScript.Echo objSubFolder.Path

    End If

    ' Test its subfolders...
    Recurse objSubFolder.Path

Next
```

Tip: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` from your code while you're developing or you might miss all kinds of bugs and cause all kinds of headaches.